# Is this a sufficient proof that the sequence is bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, real-numbers

I am working on the following problem:

> Suppose that the sequences $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ are bounded. Prove that the sequence $\{x_n+y_n\}$ is also bounded.

My proof went something like this:

```
If {xn}is bounded, then there is a real number a such that |xn| <= a , for all natural n

If {yn}is bounded, then there is a real number b such that |yn| <= b , for all natural n

Then, x+y <= a+b and x+y >= -a-b for all x in {xn}, y in {yn}.

So |xn + yn| <= a + b for all natural n

Therefore the sequence {xn + yn} is bounded.
```

However when I googled the question, I'm seeing all kinds of stuff with limits and so on. Is this proof not sufficient? Am I doing something wrong / making an assumption I can't?

If so, what would be a correct proof for this?

Comment: Do you know the triangle inequality? It should simplify matters for your suggested proof. (And it would be good if you can place your math notations in dollar signs like instead of xn + yn you should type \$ x_n + y_n \$ and it will appear as $x_n+y_n$ or \$ \{ x_n \} \$ and it will appear as $\{x_n\}$.

Comment: Limits are not relevant to this question.

Comment: yes, it is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is fine: your notation is a bit odd, there's no need to introduce $x$ and $y$; and you did skip a step.

You should add that since $|x_n| < a$ it follows that $-a < x_n < a$, and since $|y_n| < b$ it follows that $-b < y_n < b$. Therefore $-a-b < x_n+y_n < a+b$ and then finish the proof as before.

You could also employ the triangle inequality to make the proof even shorter, as suggested in the other answer.

Also, please learn to use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to typeset the mathematics in your questions.

Answer (score 3):

It is quite correct. In fact, you just need the triangular inequality :

$$(\forall n\in \Bbb N)\;|x_n+y_n|\le |x_n|+|y_n|$$
$$\le a+b$$
You don't need to use the inequality
$x_n\ge -a$.